# Was this question too broad?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, needs-more-focus

I asked the question [Is data from a HTTPS POST request secure on the client-side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71228164/is-data-from-a-https-post-request-secure-on-the-client-side) the other day. To my surprise, it was closed as too broad by the end of the day.

To my mind, the question outlines a clear, practical problem that I was facing while in the process of creating my web app, and which I needed to make a decision on. It focused on only one question, and all that was required to answer it is an understanding of how HTTPS requests work.

Was my question rightfully closed?

Comment: eh, well, "secure" itself is... well, there's a lot of layers to it.

Comment: But it's defined in the question as "visible to end users"

Comment: True, and... that's... again dependant on how hidden you need it to be. If your code on the client needs to be able to act on/interpret that data... the user can read it, if they have the technical know how.

Comment: In the question I defined it as visible with methods like inspecting of browser tools and other more advanced methods. Your comment is a clarification of what I suspected and so would have been a perfectly valid answer, but the question was closed instead

Comment: honestly i don't necessarily agree with "needs more focus" directly... but... it's asking something that is just at such a fundamental level to client/server communication, that if you don't understand it, there's probably a lot more about this communication method that you're missing. For the client to read it, the client, aka the end user, can read it. no amount of encrypting changes that, because that all happens at the client if the client can read it. Put another way... Asking if it is secure... isn't really the correct question.

Comment: I don't think it's ever a bad idea to explicitly clarify the fundamentals, there are many questions on the site that do that as it is, especially when those fundamentals relate to security. Not everyone reads write ups and white papers on how HTTPS works, questions that clarify the basics can be very helpful to everyday developers just trying to build things securely

Comment: If the data is “not visible to end users”, how could it be displayed by the browser at all? Data transferred via https, either from or to the browser needs to be known by the browser, logically.

Comment: does *"can users read an https response, via dev tools or any other way?"* effectively boil down your question to a single sentence?

Comment: I ask because surely there's an example of this very question out there on SO somewhere, but i'm not seeing it

Comment: @KevinB More or less, although the part about how HTTPS is encrypted is directly relevant - what you say makes sense if HTTPS encrypts in transit, but even that I couldn't find any definitive questions on it, neither here nor in security.SE.

Comment: I think the question boils down to a misunderstanding about how the client-server communication works and how https encryption works. It’s hard to answer because it does not make much sense. If the browser is the one making the POST request, how could data be “secured from it” in any way?

Comment: In the end the question what really is is “how does https encryption works”.

Comment: @yivi I'm specifically talking about the common practice of sending data back with the response, as detailed in the question, so the data is coming from the server.

Comment: Well, the title of the question mentions the POST request. _”Is data from a HTTPS POST request secure on the client-side?”_. The client is making the request. But in any case, request or response, is the same thing. The browser needs to be able to read the response, and to craft the request. So logically it needs to “know” the content for both.

Comment: It's a bit unclear why you a trying to achieve what you are asking for - there is no way to hide the data you are sending from the client - it is always be available (for example, via devtools). You can *obscure* the data being sent via any means necessary (i.e. by encrypting it beforehand), but there is no way you can *hide* the fact the data is being sent. You can hide the *response* from the server via opaque response but then you will not be able to read the data client-side.

Comment: Both ends encrypt/decrypt the data. Again, what you really need answering is “how does HTTPS work”. And maybe something more to clarify what’s a “request” and what’s a “response” in this process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not think the question itself is too broad.  An answer could be provided in 5-10 paragraphs of explanation which in my book means it's perfectly answerable as is.

But, what makes questions like this harder to answer is that there are some basic misconceptions expressed in the question and answering your question requires enough explanation to first dispel and explain the parts of the question itself that are wrong and then focus on answering the underlying question.  This tends to frustrate people trying to answer because the question itself has faults.  And, when you frustrate people trying to answer by providing a flawed question, you may get downvotes or closevotes, whether the downvoting or closevoting reason is perfectly aligned with why a question should be closed or not.

The flaws do make the question seem a bit unfocused because you're not focusing the question on the proper issues and some other things have to also be explained in order to write a decent answer.

The (somewhat obvious, but not always easy to do) answer here is to write better questions that don't frustrate people who are trying to answer your question.

What I think probably put people off is this:

> I recently read somewhere that HTTPS requests are only encrypted in transit (as opposed to end-to-end) in order to prevent MITM attacks, which seems to imply that they are unencrypted on the ends themselves.

HTTPS is end-to-end encrypted.  It's encrypted from when it leaves the browser to when it is delivered to the server's code (that's end-to-end).  Thus, it is also encrypted in transit.

So, the question is very confused about this.

> If this is true, it would mean that the user is able to see them on the client-side, making data sent to them insecure.

Then, this is also confused.  All data that exists on the client-side is potentially viewable by the user (with a small amount of coding skill).  The entire client-side is insecure from the client itself.  That is just a truism of the client-server architecture.  So, the notion that you could merge in some data with your client-side code and that data could never be viewable by the client is just misguided.

In your client, the data sits in some user-visible form in plain text.  Then, the user carries out some action to submit the data to the server.  Your client-side code receives the data in plain text, merges in some more data in plain text and then calls some function to initiate the https request.  Up to now all the data is being managed by your client-side code and it's all in plain text.  A coder of moderate skill with access to the client could follow what was happening.

When the function is called to make an https request, the underlying code established the https connection to the server and this includes negotiating encryption mechanisms.  The data is then encrypted (before it leaves your client-side process) and the data is sent over TCP to the server fully encrypted.

It's not viewable by anyone on the network or even in the local OS because it is end-to-end encrypted.

But, while the data was being assembled in the client (before the https request was sent), it was viewable by anyone with access to your client and some coding/hacking skills.

Comment: I appreciate your detailed exposition of the question and how it was likely perceived, and I think you're right, but it seems to me that any of these problems could easily have been edited out and/or answered as quickly as you have here *while* explicitly answering the question at the same time (and that's basically what you have done here). Essentially, what I take from this is that the SE community paradoxically expects askers to know what they don't know; if I knew exactly what I should or shouldn't be asking as part of a question, I wouldn't be asking the question in the first place.

Comment: @HashimAziz - Yep, that's how things work here.  For its good and its bad.  In the ideal world, you'd leave some commented feedback, suggesting how the question needs to be fixed and, if the OP has ignored the feedback after some reasonable amount of time, then and only then, would you vote to close or downvote.  But, much of stackoverflow is more "hit and run" then that.

Comment: @HashimAziz - Part of it is that there is no easy mechanism to leave feedback and then come back later to see if the feedback was ignored or incorporated.  There's no "to do list" it automatically gets placed in that makes it easy to check back on it later.  In fact, it's fairly manually to find it again and check on it again.  It could be useful from a readers point of view to have a feature to vote to close if not modified in x hours. Obviously, not every modification would "fix" the question, but that would at least cover the questions that are not modified at all.

Comment: @HashimAziz - I also think there's a rush to judgment on whether a question "could" be considered something to close rather than figuring out if there "is" a way to answer it even though it is flawed.  Many close votes come on questions that could be perceived to align with a closable reason even though there are other ways to answer that would work for everyone.  I run into that regularly.  Yours was one of those.

Comment: @HashimAziz - It's also a problem that it's virtually impossible for regular users to ever reopen something that has been closed.  So, even if you come back later and fix your question after its been closed, it is almost never the case that enough people come back and vote to reopen to actually get it reopened.  I vote to reopen all the time (as I did on yours) and it pretty much never gets enough reopen votes from others to succeed.  I also don't get a notification if it does get reopened.  So, once it's closed, its pretty much dead.  I advise people to post their fix in a new question.

Comment: @jfriend00 if you follow a post, you do get notifications about any change made to it, including editing, comments, reopen/reclose, etc - why do you not get notifications?

Comment: @OlegValter - Didn't know about "Follow" or what it did.  Have never used it.  Will try it in the future.

Comment: @jfriend00 figured as much :) it's not ideal, but it helps a ton for keeping an eye on posts. I ended up following everything I interact with in significant manner at a cost of having to read through a huge bunch of notifications every day (the biggest drawback of the feature - some grouping or a way to subscribe to only certain events would be great, but alas)

Answer (score 7):

Personally I don't think the naked, context-free question itself is too broad - asking if an HTTPS POST is secure seems like a reasonable question to ask -  but the explanation/justification of the answer could *become* broad.

Ultimately this is a question rooted in basic understanding of how secure sessions work, and who it's secure from, which underscores *quite a lot* of information to distill to you.

Worse, it may not even be the question you need answered.  Asking if a session is secure is **fundamentally different** than asking if a client sending a request to a host is sending that request in an obscured fashion such that the client wouldn't be able to inspect it.

Comment: Aren't PHP sessions a completely different technology to HTTP(S) requests?

Comment: No, they aren’t. They are cookies, which are transferred using the same protocol than the rest of the request. Add “how do ‘sessions’ work” to the list of questions. There is part of the session that can be stored in the backend, inaccesible to the end user, though. That’s not necessarily the case. But that’s a different question and discussion.